# Reading a parquet file in Driver class

Tags: mapreduce, parquet

I have a parquet input file. I want to read that input file in my driver class and do some processing to set my configuration of the job.

Please give me some inputs about this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is how do read a parquet file in my job class. I was searching for the classes for doing that. I have found the solution and will update here soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following way to read the Parquet file in my driver class.

```
 ParquetMetadata readFooter = ParquetFileReader.readFooter(configuration, parquetFilePath);
MessageType schema = readFooter.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
ParquetFileReader parquetFileReader = new ParquetFileReader(
    configuration, parquetFilePath, readFooter.getBlocks(), schema.getColumns());
BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvOutputFile));
PageReadStore pages = null;
try {
  while (null != (pages = parquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup())) {
    final long rows = pages.getRowCount();
    LOG.info("Number of rows: " + rows);

    final MessageColumnIO columnIO = new ColumnIOFactory().getColumnIO(schema);
    final RecordReader<Group> recordReader = columnIO.getRecordReader(pages, new GroupRecordConverter(schema));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      final Group g = recordReader.read();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that `readFooter` is deprecated.  You can get the same thing with:  `ParquetFileReader.readFooter(configuration, inputPath, ParquetMetadataConverter.NO_FILTER)`